StoreKit Configuration File doesn't sync for newly created App in Xcode 16
I created a new App in AppStoreConnect and set subscriptions informations for it.
Then

I open the corresponding project in Xcode 16
Create a new StoreKit Configuration File
Chose to sync with App Store Connect and selected the app I created
When I click the StoreKit Configuration File I just created, it is totally blank, nothing showed up. Also no any error information.

In the same project, when I used the same way to create other StoreKit Configuration Files which were synced with the Apps I already released, they showed correct IAP information.
It is so confusing. I googled but did not find any similar case.
Any hint would be appreciated!

Solved!
The key is the subscription status should be "Ready to Submit" but mine is "Missing Metadata".
I filled up all necessary items but did not upload a screenshot, so the status is still "Missing Metadata". After I uploaded a screenshot, the status changed to "Ready to Submit". And I finally can sync my StoreKit Configuration file now.

Mine is aleady wait for review, still not showing up.

I have different bundle identifier for development environment. The products on this identifier were not ready-to-submit because they are not meant to be submitted. Xcode 15 syncs these products but Xcode does not. Thanks.

This was the solution, Xcode 16.1 only syncs In-App Purchases that have a screenshot, i.e. does not sync when there are "Missing Metadata".

To clarify: for me, the in-app purchase status needed to be on "Ready to Submit" so not just the app itself(!)
Thank you for your solution by the way. This saved me a lot of work and frustration.

My inapp purchases show only when they are approved, not before, not in any other status. I

I upgraded to Xcode 16, but the StoreKit file stopped working. I decided to downgrade to Xcode 15.4, and now I can sync the StoreKit file without any issues. That turned out to be the solution for me :)
